# Can't retrieve MongoDB collection in Git Bash (Windows)

Tags: mongodb

This is the exact steps that I followed:

```
User@User-PC MINGW64 /
$ mongo
2016-02-22T10:02:33.474+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: test
use dev
switched to db dev
show collections
Building
_SCHEMA
db.building.find()
```

After doing `db.building.find` nothing outputs; no error, nothing.

Maybe I'm trying to fetch the collection in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection name is `Building`, so please try

```
db.Building.find({})
```

rather than

```
db.building.find()
```

Comment: I tried that and I got `db.Building.find({})
2016-02-22T10:18:34.324+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:18`

Comment: @alexchenco, the result in local test, `> db.Building.find({})
 >  { "_id" : ObjectId("56ca6e26036ac8a37707b6f0"), "ky" : 123 }` test under Git Bash...

Comment: @alexchenco, or may you try `db.Building.find()`?

Comment: I was using Git Bash (Windows). I used Cgwin instead and it worked. Weird.

Comment: @alexchenco, the error you met indicates the illegal character is `{`, it is weird....

Comment: Maybe Git Bash was inserting an empty space somewhere. I could navigate the command line with the arrows (even inside mongo shell).